# How to work around not bundled libs with webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have an issue with mr. WebPack. Back-end application. In webpack.sls.config.js I have settings

```
externals: ['@typedorm/core', '@typedorm/common']
```

This settings is important because this two libs are web pack unfriendly - they can’t be bundled. But working repo uses both of this libs and after deploy and attempt to call graphql end point I have “Cannot find module @typedorm/core”.
It was context.
What I tried to do:

```
externals: {
  '@typedorm/core': './node_modules/@typedorm/core',
  '@typedorm/common': './node_modules/@typedorm/common',
 },
 plugins: [
  new CopyPlugin([
   { from: '../../node_modules/@typedorm', to: '../node_modules/@typedorm' },
  ]),
 ],
```

I could move node module to .webpack and application tries to call libs by way which I shown, but I still same error. In logs I see now that application looks for libs by new route (./node_modules/@typedorm/core), but still can’t find it.
Does anyone has idea how should I handle it?

Comment: When you use externals, you are telling Webpack that you will be loading those libraries separate, client-side. I.e. your html has `<script async defer src="..."></script>` instructions for loading those libraries. And if that code shouldn't even ever load in the browser, then you have more work to do, because then Webpack shouldn't even be giving an entry point that leads to importing the code that uses those libraries.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But how to handle it in Back-end application?

Comment: Why would Webpack be relevant to your backend? Your backend just runs the code itself, not a packed/bundled version.

Comment: In my working application we bundle application code and deploy it to lambda service.

Comment: That sure sounds like something [you should have put in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Please read those posting guidelines and [edit] your post accordingly so that it properly describes your actual use-case, including setting the relevant tags.

Comment: I had put that it is back-end application.

Comment: And regular backend applications are nothing like lambda deployments. You don't bundle a regular backend applicaiton, it just runs node, on your source code.